# British Indian Ocean Territory time problem

Tags: time

I've been stationed in the British Indian Ocean Territory and I find Ubuntu does not seem to have a time zone for this place. Anyone can help? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as British Indian Ocean Territory's timezone is not in Ubuntu, you can try these steps to set it:

1. Open a Terminal
2. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
   ```
3. Select `None of the above`.
4. Select `GMT+6`.
5. The time should now be set correctly.

---

Alternatively,

You can look for a country in the *Time & Date* map with the same timezone as yours.

Otherwise, you should be able to set your time manually if you can't find the country.

1. Open *Time & Date*.
2. Change "Set the time" to "Manually".
3. Enter the current time into the appropriate fields.

Comment: @wow456 If my answer helped you then you can click on the checkmark under the voting buttons to accept it.